# Matlab Parallel Parametrized Unit Tests isn't logging error data needed for JUnit XML Writer

Tags: xml, matlab, unit-testing, junit, parallel-processing

**CONTEXT:**

I had a parametrize Matlab Unit Test running fine with the Junit/Matlab XML plugin. After completing all my test, it wrote a convenient Junit format xml file of all tests results. But, I decided to make my test run in parallel because of time consideration. Then, I discovered that my convenient MATLAB plugin was never designed to run in parallel.

```
Error using
matlab.unittest.internal.TestRunnerExtension/runInParallel
(line 33)
The matlab.unittest.plugins.xml.JUnitXMLOutputPlugin plugin
does not support running in parallel.
```

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.xmlplugin-class.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testrunner.runinparallel.html

**ACTION:**

So I lost a feature, by adding a new one. No matter, I wrote a new Junit Format XML writer(see JUnitXMLTestWrite.m), that could use testResultObj to write the xml file after the run function instead of inside the run function below.

```
testResultObj = runner.run(suite);
and
testResultObj = runInParallel(runner,suite)
```

**EXPECTED:**

I expected to use testResultObj inside JUnitXMLTestWrite and write a complete and working Junit/Matlab XML file.

**RESULT:**

But, my test aren't logging error data in testResultObj when I run it in parallel.
All my testResultObj(1,i).Details are empty structures. Hence, my JUnitXMLTestWrite is writing a complete Junit/Matlab XML file without error results.

**GOAL:**

How can I log (1.error data 2. name or id of test) inside of a parametrize unit test run for failed cases and store it in my workspace after the test are done running ? Hence to be able to use with it JUnitXMLTestWrite and log error in string format.

**INFO:**

I do see error logging display in my command window when running parpools, hence they do exist.

This is what I tried:

1. Reading Mexeption & Try/Catch

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexception.html

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html

2. wrapping the function that fails(inside of my tested function) with:

```
    try
        %% DO STUFF
    catch ME
        %% CLEAN,CLOSE,CLEAR ENV,WINDOWS,MEMORY
        %% LOG ERROR
        ErrLog = [ME.identifier, ME.message];
        %% TROW BACK ERROR
        rethrow(ME);
    end
```

But the logged data isn't persistent inside my function, it's not added to my workspace.

Thx in advance.

**CODE:**

```
function JUnitXMLTestWrite(filename,testResultObj,testClassName)
docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('testsuites');
testsuites = docNode.getDocumentElement;
testsuites.setAttribute('version','2.0');
testsuite = docNode.createElement('testsuite');
n = 0;
m = 0;
p = 0;
for i = 1: length(testResultObj)
testcase{i} = docNode.createElement('testcase');
testcase{i}.setAttribute('classname',testClassName);
testcase{i}.setAttribute('name',testResultObj(1,i).Name);
testcase{i}.setAttribute('time',string(testResultObj(1,i).Duration));
%%%Log Error Messages
if testResultObj(1,i).Failed && testResultObj(1,i).Incomplete
    n = n + 1;
    error{n} = docNode.createElement('error');
    error{n}.appendChild(docNode.createTextNode("**MISSING CRUCIAL INFO RIGHT HERE**"));%testResultObj(1,i).Details%
    testcase{i}.appendChild(error{n});
elseif testResultObj(1,i).Failed && ~testResultObj(1,i).Incomplete
    m = m + 1;
elseif ~testResultObj(1,i).Failed && testResultObj(1,i).Incomplete
    p = p + 1;
end
testsuite.appendChild(testcase{i});
end
testsuite.setAttribute('error',string(n));
testsuite.setAttribute('failures',string(m));
testsuite.setAttribute('name','');
testsuite.setAttribute('skipped',string(p));
testsuite.setAttribute('test',string(length(testResultObj)));
testsuite.setAttribute('time',string(sum([testResultObj(1,:).Duration])));
testsuites.appendChild(testsuite);
xmlwrite(filename,docNode);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The XML plugin now supports running in parellel starting from R2018b, Which version of MATLAB are you using? Are you able to update?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: 1) I'm using R2017b. Work Provided. Is there a way to download that latest plugin individually?
2)Is there a way to log error messages as you run? My new code works, i'm only missing that.

Comment: It is not just the plugin but also the architecture of the runner that enables the single xml file to be produced from multiple parallel workers. Note in R2018a there was the ToUniqueFiles output stream that enabled these diagnostics to be included in multiple TAP streams, which is more straightforward to implement (ibeleive theres similar pseudocode on SO somewhere). Also, you may be interested in getting this data using the Diagnostics in the Details of the TestResult using https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.plugins.diagnosticsrecordingplugin-class.html

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I found out how to log Error messages in a text file. It runs inside of my test cases, catches errors in a try/catch block, logs it, and retrow it, giving control back to testcase and testrunner class.
I read and add it after my test run in my JUnitXMLTestWrite later on. This works!

**Better**:
As @AndyCambell said, If I ever upgrade to Matlab 2018, I'll use the given plugin.

**Code:**

```
    try
        %% DO STUFF
    catch ME
        %% CLEAN,CLOSE,CLEAR ENV,WINDOWS,MEMORY
        %% LOG ERROR
         ErrLog = getReport(ME);
         logError(ErrLog, sys(1:end-4));
        %% TROW BACK ERROR
        rethrow(ME);
    end
```

```
function logError(errorMessage, fileName)
    % Open the Error Log file for appending.
    fid = fopen(strcat(fileName,'.txt'), 'at');
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', errorMessage); % To file
    fclose(fid);
    save(strcat(fileName,'.mat'),'errorMessage','fileName');
end
```